# Linux: Limiting data throughput (pipe) in bytes per second?

Tags: linux, pipe, throughput

I was wandering if there is a Linux program that can limit data throughput of a pipe - in *actual* bytes per second?.

From what I gather, applicable for the purposes would be

- `bfr`, however, it has been removed from Debian ([Removal candidate: bfr](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-qa@lists.debian.org/msg13629.html))
- `cpipe`, however, it seems the lowest resolution it will support is kB/s, meaning that buffer writes can still reach MB/s ([[SOLVED] Is there a program to limit terminal pipe speed? - Page 2 - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1269034&page=2&p=10573016&postcount=11))

What I'd want is to be able to specify something like

```
cat example.txt | ratelimit -Bps 100 > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

... and actually have a single byte from example.txt sent each 1/100 = 0.01 sec (or 10 ms) to 'output'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to patch `cpipe`, you can find the patch here: [cpipe-3.0.1-singlebyte.patch](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/patches/cpipe-3.0.1-singlebyte.patch?view=markup); it's in respect to current '`apt-get source cpipe`' in Lucid (which gets me cpipe_3.0.1.orig.tar.gz and cpipe_3.0.1-1.diff.gz); when the source downloads and unpacks the `cpipe-3.0.1` dir, simply do:

```
$ cp -a cpipe-3.0.1 cpipe-3.0.1B
$ cd cpipe-3.0.1B
$ patch -p1 < /path/to/cpipe-3.0.1-singlebyte.patch
$ make
```

Added a command line switch -bs for 'byte single' which can now support single byte writes down to 1 Bps; so now can do:

```
$ echo "hello" | ./cpipe -vt -vw -bs 1 | cat 
./cpipe: period 1 sec, 1000.000000 ms, 1000000000 ns, 0.000000 nsrem 
h out: 1000.122ms at       0B/s (      6B/s avg)       6B
e out: 2000.343ms at       0B/s (      2B/s avg)       6B
l out: 3000.536ms at       1B/s (      1B/s avg)       6B
l out: 4000.730ms at       1B/s (      1B/s avg)       6B
o out: 5000.925ms at       1B/s (      0B/s avg)       6B

 out: 6001.100ms at       1B/s (      0B/s avg)       6B
 out: 6001.155ms at       1B/s (      0B/s avg)       6B
thru: 6001.209ms at       1B/s (      1B/s avg)       6B

$ echo "hello" | ./cpipe -vt -vw -bs 5 > /dev/null
./cpipe: period 0 sec, 200.000000 ms, 200000000 ns, 200000000.000000 nsrem 
 out: 200.120ms at       0B/s (     30B/s avg)       6B
 out: 400.323ms at       2B/s (     10B/s avg)       6B
 out: 600.507ms at       3B/s (      5B/s avg)       6B
 out: 800.690ms at       4B/s (      3B/s avg)       6B
 out: 1000.870ms at       4B/s (      2B/s avg)       6B
 out: 1201.049ms at       4B/s (      1B/s avg)       6B
 out: 1201.098ms at       5B/s (      1B/s avg)       6B
thru: 1201.142ms at       5B/s (      5B/s avg)       6B
```

... however, this won't work all too well for higher kB/s rates - so in that case, it's better to use the usual `cpipe` `-s` buffered technique ...

```
$ cat /etc/X11/rgb.txt | ./cpipe -vt -vw -bs 102400 > /dev/null
....
 out: 2675.206ms at    6.3kB/s (      1B/s avg)   17.0kB
 out: 2675.240ms at    6.3kB/s (      1B/s avg)   17.0kB
thru: 2675.832ms at    6.3kB/s (   6.3kB/s avg)   17.0kB

$ cat /etc/X11/rgb.txt | ./cpipe -vt -vw -s 100 > /dev/null
 out:   0.011ms at    1.5GB/s (   1.5GB/s avg)   17.0kB
thru: 166.630ms at  101.9kB/s ( 101.9kB/s avg)   17.0kB
```

..., as it says also in `man cpipe`:

> Since on most systems there is a certain minimum time usleep()
>   sleeps, e.g. 0.01s, it is impossible to reach high limits with a small buffer size

Well.. hope to hear there's a better way of controlling this,
Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You could try `mbuffer` (don't know if it is in Debian by default):

```
cat example.txt | mbuffer -R 100 > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Hi @bmk, thanks and +1 for your answer, as I didn't know about [mbuffer: measuring buffer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mbuffer)! Also, `sudo apt-get install mbuffer` is OK in Ubuntu.. However, `-R 100` raises '`mbuffer: fatal: invalid low value for option "-R" - missing suffix?`'; at least 101 is needed (as per [mbuffer.c](http://svn.ringlet.net/svn/ringlet/sysutils/mbuffer/branches/vendor/mbuffer/mbuffer.c)). Finally, it seems it uses the limit just to fill its own intermediate buffer - but still writes in chunks with large Bps (while it buffers, I have no activity on USB!) Thanks & cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`pv` can also do it.  Here are some moderately contrived examples:

- `pv --rate-limit 1 /dev/zero > /dev/null`
- `pv --quiet --rate-limit 16 /dev/urandom | hd`
- `pv --quiet --rate-limit 10485760 /dev/zero | gzip | hd`
- `head -c 1000 < /dev/zero | pv --size 1000 --rate-limit 150 | sha1sum`

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a Perl-only script, [cratelimit.pl](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/cratelimit.pl?revision=222&content-type=text%2Fplain) - possibly not very accurate, but seems to do the trick somewhat (`-r` argument accepts bytes per second):

```
cat whatever | ./cratelimit.pl -r=50000
```